# Ranged vs Non-ranged Integers in VHDL

Tags: fpga, vhdl

My purpose is to store values from 0 to 3.
From a synthesis point of view, which of the following would be more area efficient, when coding in VHDL ?

1. signal a: integer;
2. signal a: integer range 0 to 3;

Will the first choice take up a 32 bit register in the FPGA?

Comment: Depends how good the synthesis tool is, and the information you can provide about the range of values to the synth tool. But the ranged form guarantees area efficiency and documents what your design does. (should be `natural range 0 to 3` to make it clear you'll never allow negative values).

Comment: Without displaying your algorithm expressed in VHDL, an integer represents 32 bits and is signed in synthesis. Any uninvolved bits are eliminated during reduction. An integer subtype (strong typing) can be useful in describing numerical relationships that don't use more bits than necessary (e.g. a 17th value for what should be a 4 bit counter).

Comment: The range of `integer` is -2*31+1 to 2**31-1. It depends on your optimizer to recognize if bits 4 to 31 are unused in your case. I recommend type `unsigned(3 downto 0)` to store values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends, but **it is almost always preferable to specify the range.**

For illustration, consider this example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity naturals is 
    Port ( clk    : in  std_logic;
           rst    : in  std_logic;
           count  : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0));
end naturals;

architecture behavioral of naturals is
    signal count_intern : natural := 0;
begin
    count <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(count_intern, count'length));
    process(clk)
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
            if (rst = '1') then
                count_intern <= 0;
            elsif (count_intern = 5) then
                count_intern <= 0;
            else
                count_intern <= count_intern + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end behavioral;
```

This is a simple counter going from 0 to 5.
It's simulation looks like this:
[image: simulation]

However, I didn't limit the signal `count_intern` - so, internally it is 31-bits (integers are 32-bits, naturals are 31). Even though I am only actually using the lower 3 bits, all 31 end up in the addition and comparison operations. Why? Because on startup, the initial value of `count_intern` is undefined. It might, for instance, begin with a value of **7** - at which point, the counter will increment until all 31 bits fill up and overflow back to 0. The initialization (to 0) that I supplied in the code, only applies to simulation - it is ignored by the synthesizer.

The post-synthesis schematic, therefore, looks like this:

[image: post-synthesis1]

I realize the image is too large to make out its details - but that's the point. It's a mess; and for a very simple circuit.

Now, let's replace the single line:

> signal count_intern : natural := 0;

with

> signal count_intern : natural range 0 to 5 := 0;

Without proof, the simulation is exactly the same. However, the post-synthesis schematic now resolves to:

[image: post-synthesis2]

In fact, the results of this can be confirmed even *post-implementation* - where it truly counts:

Without limiting the natural range:
[image: post-implementation1]

With range limit:
[image: post-implementation2]

Notice the difference in flip-flops used.

While I used Naturals here, this (of course) extends to Integers as well.

*Implementation results may vary. Here I am using the default settings in Vivado 2015. Either way, the point is - it is safer and preferable to always specify the range.*

Comment: Does this apply to constants too, since the compiler should be able to deduce which bits will never be used? Like, if a constant is assigned a value of 10 but is declared with a range of 0 to 31.

Comment: @TisteAndii great question. I’ll give it a try on Monday. I would suspect that it doesn’t matter for constants, for the reason you stated.

Comment: @TisteAndii I did a few tests with constants, and it looks like your assumptions are correct. It makes sense. A constant can only ever have a single state- so there's never a reason to preserve unused or unnecessary bits from its value.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Was wondering if I should bother optimizing the size of some constants to the exact width needed